# Propeller design comparison

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, propulsion

Why does boat/airplane propellers are designed so differently then of a turbine/pump propellers? (blade spacing, pitch, blade shape and width, etc) although both just push fluids backwards

Comment: I think this  is more about engineering than physics. You might be better asking this on the [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8907/why-are-there-so-many-different-propeller-shapes/8909#8909

Answer (score 1):

The density and viscosity of the fluids involved (air and water) are very different so their flow patterns will be different. A more technical way of putting this is that the fluids have different [Reynolds numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number).